# jquery sortable drag and drop item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using sortable function to do drag and drop in my table. 
I get ui.item that will follow the mouse cursor item. But I want to get exchange item.

> Item 1
>     Item 2
>     Item 3

If I drag the Item 1 to Item 2, they will change their position.

> Item 2
>     Item 1
>     Item 3

I can use ui.item to get Item 1 data in stop event.
But I can't find any function to get Item 2 data.

How can I get Item 2 data? Thanks

Comment: Won't the item you're looking for always be the item directly above the position your just dropped the dragged item into. Ie, if new sort position is index 2. Then the item you're looking for is at index 1?

Comment: `ul.item`'s are not exchanged. The sorted item `ul.item` is just removed and inserted in the new position. If you wanna get the data of `Item 2`, use a position selector.

Comment: @Pugazh What is the position selector?

Comment: Like `ul:nth-child(1)`

Comment: I want to get Item2 for update some data in value tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
  table, tr, td, th{
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
  td {
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 550px;
  }
  td, input {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #move {
      background: #555555;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      float: right;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      line-height: 30px;
      font-family: Arial;
      cursor: move;
  }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="main" role="main">
        <table id='myTable'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:10px;text-align: center;"></th>
              <th style="width:100px;text-align: center;">Category</th>
              <th style="width:200px;text-align: center;">Document Name</th>
              <th style="width:200px;text-align: center;">Document Time</th>
              <th style="width:200px;text-align: center;">PDF File Name</th>
              <th style="width:200px;text-align: center;">Upload Time</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% if (item.length) { %>
              <% for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {%>
                <tr>  
                  <td align="center"><span id='move'>三</span></td>
                  <td id='orderTD' style='display:none;'><input id='order' value='<%=item[i].order%>'></input></td>
                  <td><input type='text' id='category' value='<%= item[i].Category %>' readonly></input></td>
                  <td><input type='text' id='docName' value='<%= item[i].docName %>' readonly></input></td>
                  <td><input type='text' id='docTime' value='<%= item[i].docTime %>' readonly></input></td>
                  <td><input type='text' id='fileName' value='<%= item[i].FileName %>' readonly></input></td>
                  <td><input type='text' id='fileUploadTime' value='<%= item[i].FileUploadTime %>' readonly></input></td>
                  <td align="center"><button id='edit'>Edit</button></td>
                  <td id='idTD' style='display:none;'><input id='order' value='<%=item[i].id%>'></input></td>
                  <td align="center"><button id='delete'>Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
              <% } %>
            <% } %> 
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          //make table rows sortable
          $('tbody').sortable({ 
              connectwith: 'tbody', 
              opacity: 0.6, 
              handle: "#move",
              axis: 'y',
              helper: function (e, ui) {
                  ui.children().each(function () {
                      $(this).width($(this).width());
                  });
                  return ui;
              },
              scroll: true,
              receive: function(e, ui) {
               alert($(e.target).attr('id'))
              }, //it give the id of dropped location console.log(ui.item[0].id);
              start: function(event, ui) {
                  ui.item.startOrder = ui.item.children('tr #orderTD').children('#order').val();
                  ui.item.startIndex = ui.item.index();
                  // alert(ui.item.index());
              },
              stop: function (event, ui) {
                  var endOrder = parseInt(ui.item.children('tr #orderTD').children('#order').val());

                  var endIndex = parseInt(ui.item.index());
                  var startOrder = parseInt(ui.item.startOrder);
                  var startIndex = parseInt(ui.item.startIndex);
                  var diff = startIndex - endIndex;
                  var json = {};
                  json.oldOrder = startOrder;
                  json.newOrder = endOrder + diff;
                  if(diff != 0) {
                    updatePDF(JSON.stringify(json));
                  }
              }
          }).disableSelection();
      });
    </script>
    </div> <!--! end of #container -->
  </body>
```